# array_unique only give me one result

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code right here :

```
$bestffffs = $db->query("SELECT * FROM chapter WHERE ch_trans = '".$wordss."' ORDER BY ch_trans DESC ");
    while($ftffffs = $db->fetch_array($bestffffs))
    {
        $bestffffrs[] = $ftffffs;

    }
    $result = array_unique($bestffffrs);
```

the MYSQL query have at least 45 results! but when I tried using `array_unique()` my results reduced down to one! am I using the code at the wrong place? I tried placing it everywhere but nothing worked!

I cannot use Group by on my MYSQL query because I want to remove duplicates from more than one field in my table. Group by will only remove duplicates for the field that I choose. If there is other soultion using MYSQL please include it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is DISTINCT. You can use DISTINCT with multiple fields:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(one and two and three...and n) FROM `your_table`...
```

Give that a shot. If that doesn't work, try:

```
SELECT distinctrow field_one, distinctrow field_two, distinctrow field_three FROM `your_table`;
```

Comment: your answer is really helpful! However, This way I will have my three fields without duplication inside them. but there is some repeated values between the fields! how can I get rid of them?

Comment: The DISTINCT and distinctrow keywords will make sure all of those fields are distinct. You can put as many fields in there as you want. If that is not helpful, can you clarify a bit more? I think I may be unclear.

Comment: DISTINCT(one and two and three) will return three fields field one field two and field three. It will basicaly show all the combination between them. what I need is taking three fields delete any repeated value and display them as one field.

Comment: Remember you can put as many fields in DISTINCT as you want. So, if you have 10 you can 1 and 2 and 3 and so on. From what you are asking, however, you might need a more complicated query, using JOINS, possible using subqueries, as well.

Answer (score 3):

Specify `SORT_REGULAR` as the second argument.

Otherwise, it compares them as strings. Any array is converted to the literal string `"Array"`, which of course means they are all "equal".

Comment: How can I specify my array when it is taken from MYSQL? Can you please explain or show me an example?